# X needed to be opened/somebody needed to open X/X needed somebody to open

Tags: word-order, passive-voice, active-voice

1. The treasure inside Helen needed to be opened.
2. Somebody needed to open the treasure inside Helen.
3. The treasure inside Helen needed somebody to open.

Do they mean the same?

Comment: The phrasing of "treasure inside Helen" sounds really unfortunate and disturbing. Maybe a bit of extra context to clear up what kind of treasure (literal or presumably metaphorical) is meant would help.

Comment: #3 needs an "it" at the end to convey the same meaning as #1 and #2.

Comment: Do #1 and #2 mean the same? I'm still confused with them. Please explain it to me. Thanks again.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Downright macabre.

Comment: #1 and #2 are different.  #2 says a person has to open the treasure.  #1 doesn't say a person has to do it.  For #1, perhaps a robot, a natural event, or an explosion could do open the treasure.

Answer (score 1):

NB: change of wording, but not syntax, to make more readable without loss of initial intent of OP.

> 1) The door inside the building **needed to be opened**.
>   2) **Somebody needed to open** the door inside the building.
>   3) The door inside the building, **needed somebody to open** *it*.

All three are understandable. #3 needs an **it** as the object to be grammatically correct.

#1 means that the door was closed and there was a reason for it to be open

> The door inside the building needed to be opened, *so we could have ventilation*.

#2 means that the state of the door being open was needed by somebody

> Somebody needed to open the door inside the building *because it was too stuffy for them.*

#3 It means that somebody was necessary to open the door, it could not open by itself.

> The door inside the building needed somebody to open it, *because it was jammed closed.*

The original phrase:

> The treasure inside Helen **needed to be opened**.

and its variations, are unfortunate and have several problems:

Taken literally, the phrase could mean that there is a treasure *physically inside* Helen which needs to be opened: 1) rarely, if ever, does this occur in real life (aside from possibly microdots embedded in spies, and smugglers swallowing gems/drugs); and if true, 2) would probably result in great harm to Helen being opened.

It could also mean that there is a *metaphorical* treasure, i.e. love or knowledge, but these are usually not **opened**. They are usually **released** or **recalled** (respectively), but *one's heart is* **opened** is a phrased used in literature.

**Treasure**, itself, is usually not **opened**. **Treasure** is discovered, uncovered, found, etc., a  **treasure chest** is **opened**. So, in this case, the awkward phrasing leaves the reader with the feeling that **treasure** is a euphemism for something else.

There are other problems with the original which are beyond the **ell** scope, so we don't need to go into them...